# Is there any way to change the fore color of the date Time picker in C#

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if I can do it with a piece of code resembling the one below on mouse hover:

```
    private void dobDateTimePicker_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dobDateTimePicker.CalendarForeColor=BLUE;
    }
```

Comment: im specifically for a way to do it programmatically.

Comment: dobDateTimePicker.CalendarForeColor = Color.Blue; should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dobDateTimePicker.ForeColor = Color.Green;


 dobDateTimePicker.CalendarForeColor = Color.Blue; //This line of code will do it for you.
```

**EDIT:** You may also be required to add the `EnableVisualStyles()` method before this can be achieved.

Comment: thanks, I m sure I need to add the  EnableVisualStyles()  method since without there is no effect my question is where and how do I add this EnableVisualStyles() method thanx again

Comment: EnableVisualStyles() will be placed within your 'static void Main()' method.

Comment: If this worked, please mark the answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `System.Drawing.Color` structure for this.

```
using System.Drawing;

dobDateTimePicker.CalendarForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Note this remark's excerpt from `DateTimePicker.CalendarForeColor` MSDN page:

> Starting with Windows Vista and depending on the theme, setting this
>   property might not change the appearance of the calendar. For example,
>   if Windows is set to use the Aero theme, setting this property has no
>   effect. This is because an updated version of the calendar is rendered
>   with an appearance that is derived at run time from the current
>   operating system theme. If you want to use this property and enable
>   the earlier version of the calendar, you can disable visual styles for
>   your application.